# How can I access two WebAPI endpoints within the same file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Currently the setup I have includes two WebAPI endpoints (POST and DELETE) that are located within the same C# file:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/authorizations/create/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult CreateAuthorization(string id);

[HttpDelete]
[Route("api/authorizations/delete/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteAuthorization(string id);
```

I can POST to the first endpoint successfully using Postman, but when I attempt to send a DELETE request to the second endpoint I get the following message

```
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name 
changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Testing both of these endpoints locally worked just fine, but when I upload my project to a Staging environment I'm only able to access the POST endpoint.

Any idea why I can only access one? Again, these two endpoints are located within the same Controller file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your runtime hosting environment. If it's something like IIS (or any other), `DELETE` verb mightn't be enabled.

Comment: This was the case. Thanks! I didn't know those settings existed within IIS.

Comment: @Delfino No problem, it's a common issue :D